# How to give sudo access to a bash script?

Tags: bash, sudo, sudoers

I have a bash script (`chbr.sh`) to change my display brightness from terminal as my brightness keys doesn't work.

```
sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=30`
```

Now, every time I run that script it asks for my password, which I don't like. So, I googled a little and found out that one can edit `/etc/sudoers` file to disable the password feature.

So, I edited my `sudoers` file with the below content

```
ronnie ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/ronnie/chbr.sh
```

Now when I run my script as `./chbr.sh` it again asks for my password. So, is this not the right way to give sudo access to a bash script or what am I doing wrong here?

```
ronnie@ronnie:~$ ls -l chbr.sh
~rwxrwxr-x 1 ronnie ronnie 46 Jul 13 15:59 /home/ronnie/chbr.sh
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your script is entirely correct, but you need to execute it with the full path:

```
$ sudo /home/ronnie/chbr.sh
```

Comment: Is there any way I can run this script at startup.?

Comment: If you run it at startup, you do not need to sudo it. Depending on your system there are different approaches (init.d, upstart, ...)

Comment: I just installed openbox. So, can I just add `sudo /home/ronnie/chbr.sh` to my `autostart.sh`

Comment: Of course you can run the script during the startup process, but you don't need sudo for that; startup processes are started with root privileges anyway. Just add the script to `/etc/rc.local`.

Comment: `$ touch temp.sh` `$ sudo temp.sh` `sudo: temp.sh: command not found` Mac Os X 10.8

Comment: @Nakilon: `chmod +x temp.sh; sudo ./temp.sh`

Answer (score 3):

Do you run `sudo /home/ronnie/chbr.sh`?

With the content of the file being

```
setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=30
```

Or you allow user ronnie to sudo `setpci` without password:

`ronnie ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/setpci` <-- or whatever path your setpci resides in.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who stumbles into this old question. You don't need `sudo` to change the brightness. It can be done with the “light” program where the

```
light -A 5
```

increases brightness with 5 and

```
light -U 5
```

decreases the brightness with 5.

Comment: It *does* require sudo in my case.

Comment: Light or or your script? Well you can add your script to sudoers (there's plenty of other threads on that) but make sure to restrict writing/editing Og your file as it will otherwise become insecure.